# How to display customer address in Textarea insteadof selectbox in Checkout page in Mag

Tags: checkout, recurring-billing, magento-1.9

I am trying to display all address of customer in Textarea in shipping address and billing address of checkout page instead of selectbox,  where customer should have the option to choose among their list of address.Anybody help me to achieve it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Plesae remove/comment the dropdown and customize the file.Please try this way.

```
<?php
$session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');
$cidData = $session->isLoggedIn();
$cidvar = $session->getId();

$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')
        ->load($cidvar); //put customer id here
$data = array();
$i = 0;
foreach ($customer->getAddresses() as $address) {
    $data[$i] = $address->toArray();
    $i++;
}

foreach ($data as $values) {
    ?>
    <div id="<?php echo $values['entity_id'] ?>">
        <pre>
                    <strong><?php echo $values['firstname']; ?></strong>
            <?php echo $values['city']; ?>
            <?php echo $values['region']; ?>
            <?php echo $values['street']; ?>
        </pre>
        <form>
            <p>
                <a class="group1" href="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl() . 'customer/address/edit/id/' . $values['entity_id']; ?>?popupEdit=1&meth=billing" >  
                    <input type="button"  value="EDIT" class="gray_btn"/>
                </a>
            </p>
        </form>
    </div>  
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response stalinrajindian. Please can you tell me in which file I have try the above code. Once tell me the exact path of the file.

Comment: Please try this location : app/design/frontend/default/your_theme/template/persistent/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml

Comment: Hi stalinrajindian,How to load Pincode and Country.

Comment: <?php echo $values['postcode']; ?>                               <?php echo $values['country_id']; ?>

Comment: Hi stalinrajindian, Sorry for disturbing you again and again.. I need to select one address among the displayed addresses. And new address option should be like a button. Selected address should be taken as Billing address.

Comment: <?php echo $values['country_id']; ?>  is returning only IN.

Comment: If you have more doubts please ping me on skype(Id : stalinraj j).